# Do we have Button down property as Boolean

Tags: .net, winforms, delphi, c#-4.0, dfm

I am assigned to convert delphi code to .Net, and was wondering if we have down property of button as in delphi has?
As answered in this link 
[How to make a Delphi TSpeedButton stay pressed if it's the only one in the group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202702/how-to-make-a-delphi-tspeedbutton-stay-pressed-if-its-the-only-one-in-the-group)

Can we achieve this behavior in .Net Button control?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use [CheckBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.aspx) control. Set [Appearance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.appearance.aspx) property to Button to make it look like a toggle button.

Comment: +1. That's essentially the inverse of the Delphi model, which has a button that you tell to act like a check box, instead of a check box that you tell to look like a button. At the OS level, buttons and check boxes are the same control, so the two models are equivalent.

Comment: `TSpeedButton` is not a standard Win32 API button, it is a custom-made custom-drawn control.  `TButton` and `TBitBtn` are standard Win32 API buttons.

Comment: Thanks Alot, I never used that checkbox control act like a button, have learned new thing from you guys, Now I am using it. Thanks again